# Set text-size for part of the string

Tags: android, android-edittext

I had two strings:

```
<string name="bigtext">Big text</string>
<string name="anothertext">Small text</string>
```

I need them both in EditText's android:hint.

I tried to combine them & put "Big text" into `<b>Big text</b>`:

```
<string name="test">"<b>Big text</b> \nSmall text"</string>
```

"Big text" is bold, yep. But how to specify that "Big text" should have bigger font than "Small text"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<big>` tags around the big text. Or, if you prefer, add `<small>` tags around the small text. However, those will not work in a string resource AFAIK -- you would need to have this string in Java code or something, using `Html.fromHtml()` to get the `SpannedString` you would feed to `setHint()` on `EditText`.